# Expanding Window Size for NLTK from_document Collocation Method

Tags: python, loops, nlp, nltk

Using NLTK to analyze a nestled list of numbers. Each sublist is independent from the others, so I used the `from_document` method. However, unlike the `from_words` method, `from_document` does not have a window size input. I want to expand the window size such that it matches each document size. My code so far:

```
 split_list = [[6, 3, 7, 8, 7, 5, 8, 8, 8, 3, 2, 1, 4],
 [5, 7, 8, 1, 8, 10, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 5],
 [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 3, 11],...]


bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(split_list)
finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi)
```

output:

```
 [((10, 4), 2.6544750245287965),
 ((1, 4), 2.270073203392851),
 ((2, 1), 1.6606985694144463),
 ((10, 10), 1.3898880959117932),
 ((4, 1), 1.2139301253553185),...]
```

But this only solves for bigrams with a window size of 2, when I want all possible bigrams from a document (e.g. window size = document size). I could go through and calculate everything manually using `itertools.combinations` to make all the combinations of bigrams, calculate their frequency, and use the non-iterated frequency of the unigrams to eventually get the pmi. However, this seems like a very roundabout way. Is there any way I could get NLTK to expand the window size?

Comment: did you get anywhere further?

Answer (score 0):

Note this question was posted a while ago but if anyone else is wanting something similar..Try using BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens, window_size) for each document, then combine resulting bg and word frequency distributions (fds) and manually construct new collocation finder from fds to score ngrams. See http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html for examples of collocation finder from freq dist.